# How can enable credential manager on windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, credentials

I have a machine with windows 7 in the domain, in the server we share a folders.
The problem is when i try con map a drive in the machine with windows 7 i have acces in the folder but i have to write a username and password of the server everytime that power on the machine.

i check the credential manager on control panel and the option is disable and i don't know how to enable it save it and don't write the password every time that i log in

Comment: Is there a GPO in place to disable credential manager?